# Why arrays declared in parent class not visible in child class during inheritance in java?

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance

```
class Parent
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int[] array=new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
    }
}
class Child extends Parent
{
    int x=array[2];
    public void MyPrint()
    {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

The error which I am getting is,

> Main.java:18: error: cannot find symbol int x=array[2];
>         ^ symbol:   variable array location: class Child 1 error

Yes we can pass the array as arguments to the method and the code will compile. But why is this approach leading to an error even though the class and method in which the array has been declared is public?

Comment: Because the array isn't declared "in the parent class" but in a method.

Comment: As tkausl said you did not define array in the parent class. You should read up on scope of variables.

Comment: Indeed - you need to learn about the differences between *local variables* and fields.

Comment: Thanks @tkaus!. What a blunder i was making.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *But why is this approach leading to an error even though the class and*
>   *method in which the array has been declared is public?*

even though the method is declared public does not mean you can get access to objects declared inside of it...

**int[] array** belongs to the static method main and not to the class, the scope is compl. different and you will never be able to read/write that object unless you modify the scope..

Answer (score 0):

Because the array is NOT declared in the parent, but in the main method. You have to declare a member variable:

```
class Parent
{
    protected int[] array=new int[]{1,2,3,4,5}; // will be visible for the Child
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`int[] array` is declared inside a method. Which makes it a [local variable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html). A local variable has limited visibility, it is visible only to the method in which it is declared. It can not be accessed even from the methods of the same class.

```
class Parent
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int[] array=new int[]{1,2,3,4,5}; // local variable, 
        // visible only inside main method
    }
}
```

If you want access a variable declared in a super class from a subclass - declare your variable as ***an instance variable.***

```
class Parent {

   int[] array=new int[]{1,2,3,4,5}; // instance variable, 
   // is visible for other methods in same class
   // and for subclasses. 

}
```